# Why is return new static() causing memory leakage? (php)

Tags: php, inheritance

I was trying to do a test and see how static() and self() are different from each other in object oriented php, so I wrote this simple code:

```
class Base{
  public function __construct(){
//    return new self();
    return new static();
  }
}

class Sub extends Base {
  public function foo(){
    echo 'yes';
  }
}

$obj = new Sub();
$obj->foo();
```

But strangely, neither of the two keywords(self/static) in the base class seem to work as I expect. What I expect is an error on using `self` and fixing that error with `static`. But now, both give the error:

> Allowed memory size of xxxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xxxx bytes)

I searched this error and it's said to be the result of a "memory leak" in the program, but I can't find where I have allowed this leakage.

P.S: Maybe I don't understand self and static properly? What I understand is that self refers to the "containing class" while static refers to the "invoking class".

Comment: I believe that self is used to return the same object, when used in static function/class context. If the function/class is not static, you should return `$this`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya But how can `$this` be used before any objects are created? Can you explain a bit more? (Do you mean self/static are used only when we're using static methods?)

Comment: You're calling the `Sub` class constructor, which in turns calls the inherited `Base` constructor. `new static()`, in this context, will call the `Base` constructor again (because you're not in the context of a method call, so no [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) yet), resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jeto according to [this Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f98922db836bf21ff48444a044c5813658f1540a) it does use late static binding, at least in PHP 7.2.4

Comment: @Jeto Nothing serious really, I was trying to write a simple example of "late static binding" in action :P

Comment: @Narnia Yes, using `new static` in the context of a method call should give the expected behavior (instantiate the class corresponding to the actual object that the method was called on).

Comment: @tkausl Nevermind, you're right. Late static binding is already enabled at that stage, it just calls the base constructor again by going through the subconstructor. My bad.

Comment: @Jeto If you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it as the correct answer. Thanks Jeto and other guys.

Comment: @Narnia Seems like you already did :) It's OK, feel free to mark your answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those commenting under my question, I think I can now see where's the error in this code. I was trying to see "late static binding" in practice, so I wrote this code, but then I saw this error and thought there's a problem with late static binding in PHP. Like always, I was wrong. The point here is that, in fact, the problem isn't with late static binding. The problem is because of bad inheritance structure in my code.

When `return new static();` is called, PHP tries to instantiate the invoking class(so late static binding is working fine) which is the `Sub` class, but because of inheritance, and because I have not overridden the constructor of the Base in Sub, PHP will try to call the Base class over again and again and thus it turns to be an infinite loop.